# Pick properties from object while respecting union

Tags: typescript

I have created a union where an event is either "off-site" or "on-site". I then create a function which can receive an event, but i want to pick some properties. TS is highlighting `enrollment.event` as invalid because he doesn't know whether it respects the union. Is it possible to some how tell it, that it does. Example:

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2FAvFAFDA8sgZQEtgJEU0AfWXAM1uNPNQEooAyKAbwCgooiAEwBcUAM7AATkWQBzANw8Avjx6hINQiTJJUGbnwFiAMgHsAxgENgRU8gCCgwZIhixo2pYA2YiIv5e1qLIAK5eXv5QXnLBYRHKqurQePSMOhT6vPxEJhbWtg5OLm6iUiF+hoHAsQC2AEYQkpHRsrUNTQlq4MlwyJKm4TUZmFlQIUKiEtJykRC61ZppzFQ0qdrLiio8tCHI5jZ24pZIvf2DFFgQovDzbKPmdhJQNSCnA15DqNdv53ojhvxxiIoAByFBnD4UAC0AEYQQAaAFQOYUUSjfjZXJWA6FZyudzIgB0OTM2IKjjxbkRGIxVVEEEJVWpNKiMSJLSRKn4KiUQA

My code:

```
type TEvent = (TOnSiteEvent | TOffSiteEvent) & {
  id: string;
}

type TOnSiteEvent = {
  isLocationAddress: false;
  lat: null;
  lng: null;
}

type TOffSiteEvent = {
  isLocationAddress: true;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

type TEnrollment = {
  uid: string;
  event: TOnSiteEvent | TOffSiteEvent;
}

function saveEnrollment(e: TEvent) {
  const myEnrollment: TEnrollment = {
    uid: 'enrollment-1',
    event: {
      isLocationAddress: e.isLocationAddress,
      lat: e.lat,
      lng: e.lng
    }
  }
}
```

If I set `event` just to `event: e` then it works, as it sees it respects the union, but i just want to pick certain properties out as seen above.

I have even tried adding gaurd statements into `saveEnrollment` method above but its not fixing the problem, these were the gaurds I used:

```
if (e.isLocationAddress === true && (e.lat === null || e.lng === null)) {
  throw new Error('lat and lng must be provided for on-site events');
}
if (e.isLocationAddress === false && (e.lat !== null || e.lng !== null)) {
  throw new Error('lat and lng must not be provided for off-site events');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it individually, TypeScript doesn't know that the type of `isLocationAddress` (`true` or `false`) matches up with `lat`/`lng` (which have to be `number` in the `true` case, but `null` in the `false` case). You can do it by ensuring that you grab the event information from `e` as a unit, like this:

```
function saveEnrollment(e: TEvent) {
    const { id, ...event } = e;  // ***
    const myEnrollment: TEnrollment = {
        uid: 'enrollment-1',
        event                     // ***
    };
}
```

That way, TypeScript knows that `isLocationAddress`'s type matches with the type of `lat` and `lng`.

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2FAvFAFDA8sgZQEtgJEU0AfWXAM1uNPNQEooAyKAbwCgp+oRACYAuKAGdgAJyLIA5gG4eAXyU9QkGoRJkkqDNz4Ci4gDIB7AMYBDYEXPIAgkKFSI48WNrWANuIhKAlA+tmLIAK4+PoECPvJhkdEqahrQePSMuhQGvEEmFjZ2Ds6u7p5Q0uEBRvwhwAkAtgBGEFIxtfFQEc2tSqo86uBpcMhS5lEN2Zi5AuHCYpIy8u1QEHr1WpnMVDQZOtt9arThyJZFyBLWSCNjExRYEGLw62wz-JYOktyCQgA0UAA6IFrbLKAwBfgAekhUAAVPCalAPsgvg0QDdxj5Jqgnhi7vppoignNRFAAOQoW5YigAWgAjGTfkSBCD9EF2Rz2dC4Qigv1lEA)

---

In a comment you asked:

> This is very interesting thank you! Is there a way to do the opposite to omit? Because in my actual code event has a ton of things, omitting each one would be very difficult and more things may be added.

I can't think of a way of doing it that doesn't involve a type assertion. :-( But it's a really safe type assertion tucked away in a small reusable function:

```typescript
type ExtractSitekeys = "isLocationAddress" | "lat" | "lng";
function extractSiteEvent<T extends TOnSiteEvent | TOffSiteEvent>(e: T): Pick<TOnSiteEvent, ExtractSitekeys> | Pick<TOffSiteEvent, ExtractSitekeys> {
    const { isLocationAddress, lat, lng } = e;
    return { isLocationAddress, lat, lng } as TOnSiteEvent | TOffSiteEvent;
}
```

You **know** that's a valid assertion, even if TypeScript doesn't. Then usage is:

```typescript
function saveEnrollment(e: TEvent) {
    const event = extractSiteEvent(e);  // ***
    const myEnrollment: TEnrollment = {
        uid: 'enrollment-1',
        event                           // ***
    };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2FAvFAFDA8sgZQEtgJEU0AfWXAM1uNPNQEooAyKAbwCgp+oRACYAuKAGdgAJyLIA5gG4eAXyU9QkGoRJkkqDNz4Ci4gDIB7AMYBDYEXPIAgkKFSI48WNrWANuIhKAlA+tmLIAK4+PoECPvJhkdEqahrQePSMuhQGvEEmFjZ2Ds6u7p5Q0uEBRvwhwAkAtgBGEFIxtfFQEc2tSqo86uBpcMhS5lEN2Zi5AuHCYpIy8u1QEHr1WpnMVDQZOtt9arThyJZFyKsAHtLWZ1vrADwwV6TIQuKb++tQ1OkMXxQAHxYCBiGAsMH4e7ZX50f5Mb4zfiWBySbiCMxWWz2JwuNweAA0wVsRLicigygM1SCbmA4SkFy4GIK2OKeLKpJJwXkFKg1g+eG0CJhu3hWVQfQGx1O5wk1iQIzGEwoILB2zYSKgKOQaLWUxeUluwGhqBBLAU-AA9JaoAAqe01LWotANECK8Y+SaoNWjD1etDTR1BOaiKAAchQSs9FAAtABGMMEoMCPX6ILpjOZoLWu0OoL9ZRAA)

The `Pick` part is important. Without that, we wouldn't get any error from TypeScript if you added a property to `TOnSiteEvent` or `TOffSiteEvent`; the type assertion would be wrong ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2FAvFAFDA8sgZQEtgJEU0AfWXAM1uNPNQEooAyKAbwCgp+oRACYAuKAGdgAJyLIA5gG4eAXyU9QkGoRJkkqDNz4Ci4gDIB7AMYBDYEXPIAgkKFSI48WNrWANuIhKAlDIEADuAApS5pBSoGLIAK4AtgBGEFIKQQD0WVAAVAWFRcV5UM5CEEJQ1sFhUGBRMaBG-D628Qk+PoECPvIdXUqqPOrg0Hj0jLoUBrxBJhY2dg7lbh5i0gkBLVBtwB2p6T2t-cHJaRkqahrjcMhRXUkzmHMCCcJikjLyx1AQevstFNmFQaJMdCChtcxlA4AAPaTWSzAKYAawgIHEBgARAsrLZ7E4XGtxNioNRsXsyRS+nJsUpaAlkMjCX8EVIkSiIQCADwwNmkZBCLF4bRMAHksEMbkUAB8WAgYhgLCV+GBEuoE2l4pmr34lgckm4gjM+OWRNc7nEABpdrZbbSoMoDNsgm5gAkpMhjXiloTVlaHfbdvIndURWqZfpNXRtdNUL8cvkSinU7AYdYPOlzSaoKEovIAISFlQjRnMnPiaxIO4PHxPVAKpUgth6qAG5BG-7PAUc5HqigKliZKBJwo7DtGpIgWvmR4UZv3Of1nttoLvURQADkKDrDeAAFoAIxb607ILd-RBa832-ZXKFWAACxMEif5k6VTS1W96SiUh2YZlCAA)). But with the `Pick` part, we correctly get an error in that case ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2FAvFAFDA8sgZQEtgJEU0AfWXAM1uNPNQEooAyKAbwCgp+oRACYAuKAGdgAJyLIA5gG4eAXyU9QkGoRJkkqDNz4Ci4gDIB7AMYBDYEXPIAgkKFSI48WNrWANuIhKAlDIEADuAApS5pBSoGLIAK4AtgBGEFIKQQD0WVAAVAWFRcV5UM5CEEJQ1sFhUGBRMaBG-D628Qk+PoECPvIdXUqqPOrg0Hj0jLoUBrxBJhY2dg7lbh5i0gkBLVBtwB2p6T2t-cHJaRkqahrjcMhRXUkzmHMCCcJikjLyx1AQevstFNmFQaJMdCChtcxlA4AAPaTWSzAKYAawgIHEBgARAsrLZ7E4XGtxNioNRsXsyRS+nJsUpaAlkMjCX8EVIkSiIQCADwwNmkZBCLF4bRMAHksEMbkUAB8WAgYhgLDE4SIllRfPwwIBABpYezOWiMeJZZK1RqteDxRR9fDEcjjZiza9+JYHJJuIIzPjlkTXO5xPq9sH5FBlAZtkE3MAElJkF68UtCatA8HbKG5OHqiLtTL9NQJtKbaghiNGcy-RJrEg7g8fE9UAqlSC2K6oO7kJ7-s8BRzHfngAqWJkoDl8gUdp3PUkQHXzI8KC37guG7320F3qIoAByFD1xvAAC0AEYd7qdkEe-ogre7-fsrlCrAABYmb3VBPpKJSHOCNDiC+5idFUaQ7MMyhAA)).

---

That said, you'd avoid this problem entirely if you made the site event a nested object rather than just an intersection with everything else, like it is in `TEnrollment`:

```typescript
type TEvent = {
    id: string;
    event: TOnSiteEvent | TOffSiteEvent;    // ***
};
// ...
function saveEnrollment(e: TEvent) {
    const { event } = e;                // ***
    const myEnrollment: TEnrollment = {
        uid: 'enrollment-1',
        event                           // ***
    };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2FAvFA3gKCvqASwBMAuKAZ2ACdDkBzAbjwIiVXJgHlkBlQ4BEQo0AH1hcAZpP6DhqRgSgB6ZVABUmnAF9mOUJAl8BQ9mky4lhCgBkA9gGMAhsEJ3kAQWLFqEChXJJJwAbCghmJWCXcmQAV2DgiIJghhj4xJ09A2huaVlTEQxsFnxre2dXdy8fPwCoGljwkqgo4DSAWwAjCGok-BT6Du7ezJx9cBy4ZGo7BPbCi2bYknIqWgY+qDYRTh58+TEJPJMD5l0xyVjkB0rkSickKZm5kQAKCE4DgEpipQd3KjYLZmKDaIrhJSQqEqNSadTNf7IQHtEBPWbBeYcWBol6oIqWaHLMhQADkKGeGJEAFoAIwkgA0zSU2zx0LZ7Pwqg0WiU520QA)

Comment: This is very interesting thank you! Is there a way to do the opposite to omit? Because in my actual code `event` has a ton of things, omitting each one would be very difficult and more things may be added.

Comment: @Noitidart - Ugh. :-) I can't think of a way of doing it that doesn't involve a type assertion. :-( I've updated the answer showing how, with a type assertion I'd be happy to have in my code (and I really hate type assertions). You may want to leave the question open for a couple of days to see if someone else knows how to do it without one, though (like [Titian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) or [jcallz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz), wizards both). I'd be sure to update the question with that info.

Comment: @Noitidart - Oh, wait, no. That type assertion is valid **unless** you add a property to `TOnSiteEvent` or `TOffSiteEvent`. Then it's wrong. :-( I'll keep thinking.

Comment: @Noitidart - Okay, I think it's safe now. :-) (This is why I don't like type assertions, it's so easy to get them wrong! :-D )

Comment: Oh wow thank you brother this is such a knowledge share! Thanks for your time! Studying it right now but preemptively accepting answer haha!

Comment: Oh man dude, in production it was actually a lot more stuff in the code. Your solutions above are cool but it wasn't allowing me to add stuff in typesafe way. So the only way I got it to work is doing a gaurd like this, but the bodies are exactly the same, its super nasty copy paste - https://codesandbox.io/s/twvugq - any thoughts on how to accomplish this without copy pasting? - the ts playgroudn link was too long so had to codesandbox it

Comment: @Noitidart - You can use https://tsplay.dev to do short links to the playground [like this](https://tsplay.dev/N7y0nW). Since it only links to the playground SO doesn't block it. Can you give me an example of the "a lot more stuff"? A lot more properties that you *do* copy? That you *don't* (I think we covered that above). I may be able to come up with something...

Comment: Thanks so much man! I'm even learning linking here! And thanks very much for that thought! I'll grab out that example and put it up. Thanks again very sincerely!